# implement conversion parameters function with scala

Tags: scala, reflection, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement something like **clever parameters converter function** with Scala.

Basically in my program I need to read parameters from a properties file, so obviously they are  all strings and I would like then to convert each parameter in a specific type that I pass as parameter.

This is the implementation that I start coding:

```
def getParam[T](key : String , value : String, paramClass : T): Any = {

    value match {
        paramClass match {
          case i if i == Int => value.trim.toInt
          case b if b == Boolean => value.trim.toBoolean
          case _ => value.trim
        }
    }

   /* Exception handling is missing at the moment */
}
```

**Usage:**

```
val convertedInt = getParam("some.int.property.key", "10", Int)
val convertedBoolean = getParam("some.boolean.property.key", "true", Boolean)
val plainString = getParam("some.string.property.key", "value",String)
```

**Points to note:**

- For my program now I need just **3 main type of type**: String ,Int and Boolean,
  if is possible I would like to extends to more object type
- This is not clever, cause I need to explicit the matching against every possibile type to convert, I would like an **more reflectional like approach**
- This code doesn't work, it give me compile error: "**object java.lang.String is not a value**" when I try to convert( actually no conversion happen because property values came as String).

Can anyone help me? I'm quite newbie in Scala and maybe I missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala approach for a problem that you are trying to solve is *context bounds*. Given a type `T` you can require an object like `ParamMeta[T]`, which will do all conversions for you. So you can rewrite your code to something like this:

```
trait ParamMeta[T] {
  def apply(v: String): T
}

def getParam[T](key: String, value: String)(implicit meta: ParamMeta[T]): T = 
  meta(value.trim)

implicit case object IntMeta extends ParamMeta[Int] {
  def apply(v: String): Int = v.toInt
}

// and so on

getParam[Int](/* ... */, "127") // = 127
```

There is even no need to throw exceptions! If you supply an unsupported type as `getParam` type argument, code will even not compile. You can rewrite signature of `getParam` using a syntax sugar for context bounds, `T: Bound`, which will require implicit value `Bound[T]`, and you will need to use `implicitly[Bound[T]]` to access that values (because there will be no parameter name for it).

Also this code does not use reflection at all, because compiler searches for an implicit value `ParamMeta[Int]`, founds it in object `IntMeta` and rewrites function call like `getParam[Int](..., "127")(IntMeta)`, so it will get all required values at compile time.

If you feel that writing those `case object`s is too boilerplate, and you are sure that you will not need another method in these objects in future (for example, to convert `T` back to `String`), you can simplify declarations like this:

```
case class ParamMeta[T](f: String => T) {
  def apply(s: String): T = f(s)
}

implicit val stringMeta = ParamMeta(identity)
implicit val intMeta = ParamMeta(_.toInt)
```

To avoid importing them every time you use `getParam` you can declare these implicits in a companion object of `ParamMeta` trait/case class, and Scala will pick them automatically.

---

As for original `match` approach, you can pass a implicit `ClassTag[T]` to your function, so you will be able to match classes. You do not need to create any values for `ClassTag`, as the compiler will pass it automatically. Here is a simple example how to do class matching:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect._

def test[T: ClassTag] = classTag[T].runtimeClass match { 
  case x if x == classOf[Int] => "I'm an int!"
  case x if x == classOf[String] => "I'm a string!"
}

println(test[Int])
println(test[String])
```

However, this approach is less flexible than `ParamMeta` one, and `ParamMeta` should be preferred.

Comment: Using `def getParam[T : ParamMeta](key: String, value: String): T = implicitly[ParamMeta[T]].apply(value.trim)` is also possible

Comment: Is this the only way to achieve this? I mean, I need a case object for every type? I believe in just a method with a bit of logic inside

Comment: If you really need to extend this `getParam` function with side code (having original `getParam` untouched) - that is the most canonical method to do it.

Otherwise, you can just match values like `x match { case i: Int => ... case s: String => ... }`

Comment: My initial idea was that, but it doesn't compile( I wrote above the compile error that I receive), so I'm quite curious, how can pass a parameter type?

Comment: @Maxim with the first solution(ParamMeta), am I forced to declare implicit case objects in my object or class? What if I want to use just an object or a class called for example ParamConverter, import that wherever I need and use it, without cluttering my code with implicit object declaration?

Comment: Edited answer again, it still uses implicit objects, but declarations are now much simplier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105703/discussion-between-giorgio-and-maxim).